How do DC/DC converters work as lithium battery chargers, continued
I have a 96V LiFePO4 pack (32S), 206Ah, that I would like to charge.
Obviously, 0.5C is a boat-load of current...
I want to charge it off of household single-phase 110VAC with a 30 amp breaker.
So, I will be charging at less than the 100A rate.
I am willing to live with the slower charge rate.
Can I use an AC-DC converter of, say, 116.8VDC, 50A rating, and just PWM the current down to 30 or so amps?
This would result in a constant voltage across the entire charge cycle.
As my picture asks, will the current draw from the load (the battery pack) not decrease as the battery fills up?


You hold current constant by changing voltage or hold voltage constant by changing current, so you cannot hold both constant.  You have to pick (at most) one at each point in time.

JAY PRABHAKAR - Hi, (a) Where did the diagram come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add the source name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). See the linked rule for details. (b) Also see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (c) You seem to be referring to some other post. Please explain. TY

If I have a power supply that is not going to brown out while delivering a certain amount of current, then it can maintain both voltage as well as current at the same time... So, if I want to draw 30A at 116.8VDC and my supply is designed to deliver up to 50A at that voltage, then it is not going to brown out and drop its voltage, is it? that way, all I have to do is to limit the current to under the supply's current limit and I will be able to have the set voltage AND current that I need.... The question is, will that damage the battery?
